# Div Transition With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to html and javascript. Some days back someone provided me with javascript which basically opens a hidden DIV and when other DIV is opened, the first DIV which was opened will close automatically. But now I'm having another problem which does not allow me to have a transition effect. I want a transition within this code. Please help!!!

Here is the JAVASCRIPT:

```
var divs = ["div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7", "div8"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {

    if (visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
    } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
    }
    hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
    var i, divId, div;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if (visibleDivId === divId) {

            div.style.display = "block";

        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

And the HTML goes something like this:

```
<div id="div1" onClick="toggleVisibility('div1');return false;">
<div id="div2" onClick="toggleVisibility('div2');return false;">
```

and so on.

I have tried every possible way I could find, but there is no perfect way of achieving the effect. I want the div to be hidden and when the navigation is clicked, the div should open with its contents inside with a transition. Thank you :)

Comment: The best way to achieve this is using CSS transitions on the divs.

Comment: please send me a code. and i want to achieve the effect with the javascript which i provided. as making a new javascript will make me undo all the progress i have done so far. if possible please include a javascript code with in the code i already provided. than you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). For example, this will give your divs a transition from collapsed to open over two seconds:

```
#div1 {
    transition: height 2s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

I don't know JavaScript, but you will use it to hide the div by default, then on hover or click or whichever action you decide, have it display/hide the divs relative to their respective statuses.

Answer (score 1):

As TylerH noted in the comments, the best way is to use CSS transition:

```
#mydiv { transition: opacity 2s; }
.hidden { opacity: 0; }
```

the role of the javascript could be just toggle the class `.hidden` on the element you want to hide:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").classList.toggle("hidden");
```

See working example [on the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MeKu/)

You can't achieve it by setting the `display` property, since there is no transition between *none* and *block*. You can iterate through all the divs like you do in your `hideNonVisibleDivs()` and put it together with the fiddle code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery animate

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <--- this will add Jquery

$("div").onclick(function(){
  $(this.attr("id")).fadeIn(1000); <--- this is the animation
});
```

or if you want you can use the animate function

```
https://api.jquery.com/animate/
```

Comment: please provide a solution for the current javascript i gave. thank you

Comment: just change  div.style.display = "block"; to div.fadeIn(1000); and
 div.style.display = "none"; to div.fadeOut(1000); ...... its the same solution.